# Iterate through nested json array in angular controller and get unique values and displaying in view html page

Tags: json

Here's my json I'm finding it difficult to extract the values of corresponding array required.

How to display static values from schedule array and to display them in html page.
I tried a lot with `foreach` loop and object concept.

### JSON:

$scope.sp= {"basicInfo": {
    "firstName": "Nishad",
    "lastName": "Janan",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "22-04-1993",
    "mobile": "9744444883",
    "email": "nandnonly@gmail.com",
    "availableFrom": "01-01-2016",
    "availableTo": "31",
    "enableOnlineApmt":"true",
    "enableLogin": "disabled"
    },

```
"additionalInfo": {
"qualification": "Plus Two",
"specialization": "Commerce",
"achievements": "None",
"address": "Kumbakonam",
"languages": ["malayalam", "english"],
"facebookUrl": "www.facebook.com",
"linkedInUrl": "www.linkedin.com",
"twitterUrl": "www.twitter.com",
"webPageUrl": "www.google.com"
},
"assignedservices": [2, 3, 5, 6],
"schedlueWithServices":[{
"schedule": {
"timespec": [{
"recurringType": "Weekly",
"repeatIntervals": ["1", "7"],
"startDate": "2016-07-08",
"terminator": {
"endDate": "2017-07-08",
"noOfOccurance": ""
},
"timeSlots": [{
"sTime": "09:00:AM",
"eTime": "02:00:PM"
}]
}]
},
"services": [2, 3],
"schType": "Business",
"serviceChange": "false",
"isScheduleChange": "false"

},{
"schedule": {
"timespec": [{
"recurringType": "Weekly",
"repeatIntervals": ["1", "7"],
"startDate": "2016-07-08",
"terminator": {
"endDate": "2017-07-08",
"noOfOccurance": ""
},
"timeSlots": [{
"sTime": "09:00:AM",
"eTime": "02:00:PM"
}]
}]
},
"services": [5, 6],
"schType": "Business",
"serviceChange": "false",
"isScheduleChange": "false"

}],
"isAdmin": "true"
}
```

I created function to display values from timespec but something wrong in the code .I'm not able to fix the code.If someone could help with it.

```
function schedule($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
      }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.schedlueWithServices = data.schedlueWithServices; 
    $scope.schedule = [];
    $scope.timespec=[];
    angular.forEach(data.schedlueWithServices, function(schedlueWithServices, index) {
      angular.forEach(schedlueWithServices.schedule, function(schedule, index){
        angular.forEach(schedule.timespec, function(timespec, index){
            $scope.timespec.push(timespec);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly which values you're trying to display/parse through but it should just be as simple as combining bracket notation with dot notation.

```
var obj = {
    "additionalInfo": {
"qualification": "Plus Two",
"specialization": "Commerce",
"achievements": "None",
"address": "Kumbakonam",
"languages": ["malayalam", "english"],
"facebookUrl": "www.facebook.com",
"linkedInUrl": "www.linkedin.com",
"twitterUrl": "www.twitter.com",
"webPageUrl": "www.google.com"
},
"assignedservices": [2, 3, 5, 6],
"schedlueWithServices":[{
"schedule": {
"timespec": [{
"recurringType": "Weekly",
"repeatIntervals": ["1", "7"],
"startDate": "2016-07-08",
"terminator": {
"endDate": "2017-07-08",
"noOfOccurance": ""
},
"timeSlots": [{
"sTime": "09:00:AM",
"eTime": "02:00:PM"
}]
}]
},
"services": [2, 3],
"schType": "Business",
"serviceChange": "false",
"isScheduleChange": "false"

},{
"schedule": {
"timespec": [{
"recurringType": "Weekly",
"repeatIntervals": ["1", "7"],
"startDate": "2016-07-08",
"terminator": {
"endDate": "2017-07-08",
"noOfOccurance": ""
},
"timeSlots": [{
"sTime": "09:00:AM",
"eTime": "02:00:PM"
}]
}]
},
"services": [5, 6],
"schType": "Business",
"serviceChange": "false",
"isScheduleChange": "false"

}],
"isAdmin": "true"
} 
;

  console.log(obj.schedlueWithServices[1].schedule.timespec[0].recurringType);
console.log(obj.schedlueWithServices[1].schedule.timespec[0].repeatIntervals[0]);
console.log(obj.schedlueWithServices[1].schedule.timespec[0].repeatIntervals[1]);
console.log(obj.schedlueWithServices[1].schedule.timespec[0].timeSlots[0].sTime);
console.log(obj.schedlueWithServices[1].schedule.timespec[0].timeSlots[0].eTime);
```

I used `console.log` just to prove how to get to the requested static values. All you need to do is assign them to a variable value and put that value on `$scope`

Comment: I want values of timespec array,timeslot array which are nested under schedlueWithServices

Comment: Hey tcasey ! I tried with combining bracket notation with dot notation but not displaying the static values. If you could suggest another solution asap.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which static values you want to display from the JSON object above?

Comment: recurringType,repeatIntervals,sTime,eTime these are the values I wanted to display from the JSON object

Comment: Just fixed the answer for those values. Did that answer your question?

Comment: i need to display recurringType,repeatIntervals,sTime,eTime in html page

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the answer, those values are being logged in the console. So you just need to assign to a `$scope` variable and it will work.

Comment: Is there a way to do using functions?

Comment: please help out to do the same using someother way